# Python, Determine if a string should be converted into Int or Float

Tags: python, type-conversion, decimal-point

I want to convert a string to the tightest possible datatype: int or float.

I have two strings:

```
value1="0.80"     #this needs to be a float
value2="1.00"     #this needs to be an integer.
```

How I can determine that value1 should be Float and value2 should be Integer in Python?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
def isfloat(x):
    try:
        a = float(x)
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        return False
    else:
        return True

def isint(x):
    try:
        a = float(x)
        b = int(a)
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        return False
    else:
        return a == b
```

Comment: Of course, one should test for `isint()` first, and then test for `isfloat()` only if the former returns `False`.

Comment: Well first try isint, and then use isfloat, but, if I use isint all test are passed. Do you think is better use isint() only ?

Comment: This is wrong for very large numbers. For example, float("10000000000000000.5") is 1e+16, int(1e+16) is 1e+16, yet the number is not an int.

Comment: For method isint() it would be good idea to add int(x) first thing in try. Otherwise with values like '5e0' you will get True checking for int compatibility but fail on int('5e0'). Technically 5e0 could be considered int, but that can really confuse someone.

Comment: @Alexandr True, but then `5.0` (or `1.00` as in the question) would fail as well. I don't see an easy way to accept `5.0` and, at the same time reject `5e0`.

Comment: @glglgl Well, there is always stupid way: check if x is string and there is e, + or nan present. But also it is probably wrong way. Cause 5e0 IS an integer. And still usually you will use those methods to check if you can convert string to int... I am stuck :)

Comment: Why not just checking if the string contains a dot in it? somthing like: `'.' in s`

Comment: @Navaro Does `5e-2` have a dot? No. Is it a float? Yes. Is it an int? No.

Comment: @glglgl: `'.' in s or 'e-' in s.lower()` or something like `float(int(s)) == float(s)` if it is True then it is an integer otherwise a float.

Comment: IMPORTANT NOTE: Just so that you know, float('inf') and float('nan') are evaluated as valid float numbers. You should handle those cases if you do not want to use them.

Answer (score 26):

Python `float` objects have an [`is_integer` method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#float.is_integer):

```
from ast import literal_eval
def parses_to_integer(s):
    val = literal_eval(s)
    return isinstance(val, int) or (isinstance(val, float) and val.is_integer())
```

Comment: I prefer this method as it doesn't rely on an exception as a part of the evaluation.

Comment: if s doesn't evaluate to a valid literal then it will throw an error.  Also 'False' will return as an integer which might not be what you want.  I know that you are directly answering the user's question so you solution is valid but any mouse trap can be improved.

Comment: `parses_to_integer(".0"); int(".0")` -- any idea how to get around this?

Comment: This gives a false positive for strings like `120.0`.

Comment: @DaveL17 Besides the fact that literal_eval will also except on non int/float values literal_eval takes 10 times longer to run than float casting with or without exception handling. You can timeit both methods.

Comment: @MikeL OP didn't ask about evaluating non int/float values. Fair point on the slowness of literal_eval.

Comment: @DaveL17 Python is designed to handle exceptions efficiently, unlike some other languages.  That's why it prefers the [EAFP principle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11360858/5987).

Comment: @MarkRansom Fair enough. Not trying to be argumentative, but I still prefer this method as I find it more Pythonic. If I'm in charge of what's passed to literal_eval and if speed isn't a concern, I don't see a problem. I also prefer some things that PEP8 doesn't.  <grin>

Answer (score 7):

I had to handle the case of ensuring that '1.0' gets converted to '1' when I was trying to determine the differences between two XML documents.  So I wrote this function to help me.  I also think that some of the other solutions will fail when the string literal in question is 'True' or 'False'.  At any rate this function works very well for me.  I hope that it will help you too.

```
from ast import literal_eval

def convertString(s):
    '''
    This function will try to convert a string literal to a number or a bool
    such that '1.0' and '1' will both return 1.

    The point of this is to ensure that '1.0' and '1' return as int(1) and that
    'False' and 'True' are returned as bools not numbers.

    This is useful for generating text that may contain numbers for diff
    purposes.  For example you may want to dump two XML documents to text files
    then do a diff.  In this case you would want <blah value='1.0'/> to match
    <blah value='1'/>.

    The solution for me is to convert the 1.0 to 1 so that diff doesn't see a
    difference.

    If s doesn't evaluate to a literal then s will simply be returned UNLESS the
    literal is a float with no fractional part.  (i.e. 1.0 will become 1)

    If s evaluates to float or a float literal (i.e. '1.1') then a float will be
    returned if and only if the float has no fractional part.

    if s evaluates as a valid literal then the literal will be returned. (e.g.
    '1' will become 1 and 'False' will become False)
    '''


    if isinstance(s, str):
        # It's a string.  Does it represnt a literal?
        #
        try:
            val = literal_eval(s)
        except:
            # s doesn't represnt any sort of literal so no conversion will be
            # done.
            #
            val = s
    else:
        # It's already something other than a string
        #
        val = s

    ##
    # Is the float actually an int? (i.e. is the float 1.0 ?)
    #
    if isinstance(val, float):
        if val.is_integer(): 
            return int(val)

        # It really is a float
        return val

    return val
```

The output of the unit test of this function produces:

```
convertString("1")=1; we expect 1
convertString("1.0")=1; we expect 1
convertString("1.1")=1.1; we expect 1.1
convertString("010")=8; we expect 8
convertString("0xDEADBEEF")=3735928559; we expect 3735928559
convertString("hello")="hello"; we expect "hello"
convertString("false")="false"; we expect "false"
convertString("true")="true"; we expect "true"
convertString("False")=False; we expect False
convertString("True")=True; we expect True
convertString(sri.gui3.xmlSamples.test_convertString.A)=sri.gui3.xmlSamples.test_convertString.A; we expect sri.gui3.xmlSamples.test_convertString.A
convertString(<function B at 0x7fd9e2f27ed8>)=<function B at 0x7fd9e2f27ed8>; we expect <function B at 0x7fd9e2f27ed8>
convertString(1)=1; we expect 1
convertString(1.0)=1; we expect 1
convertString(1.1)=1.1; we expect 1.1
convertString(3735928559)=3735928559; we expect 3735928559
convertString(False)=False; we expect False
convertString(True)=True; we expect True
```

The unit test code follows:

```
import unittest

# just  class for testing that the class gets returned unmolested.
#
class A: pass

# Just a function
#
def B(): pass

class Test(unittest.TestCase):


    def setUp(self):
        self.conversions = [
            # input      | expected
            ('1'         ,1         ),
            ('1.0'       ,1         ), # float with no fractional part
            ('1.1'       ,1.1       ),
            ('010'       ,8         ), # octal
            ('0xDEADBEEF',0xDEADBEEF), # hex
            ('hello'     ,'hello'   ),
            ('false'     ,'false'   ),
            ('true'      ,'true'    ),
            ('False'     ,False     ), # bool
            ('True'      ,True      ), # bool
            (A           ,A         ), # class
            (B           ,B         ), # function
            (1           ,1         ),
            (1.0         ,1         ), # float with no fractional part
            (1.1         ,1.1       ),
            (0xDEADBEEF  ,0xDEADBEEF),
            (False       ,False     ),
            (True        ,True      ),
        ]


    def testName(self):
        for s,expected in self.conversions:
            rval = convertString(s)
            print 'convertString({s})={rval}; we expect {expected}'.format(**locals())
            self.assertEqual(rval, expected)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    #import sys;sys.argv = ['', 'Test.testName']
    unittest.main()
```

Answer (score 6):

```
def coerce(x):
    try:
        a = float(x)
        b = int(x)
        if a != b:
            return a
        else:
            return b
    except:
        raise ValueError("failed to coerce str to int or float")
```

Comment: This will fail for floats. If `x == 0.5`, the line `b = int(x)` will throw a ValueError exception immediately and the `if a == b` conditional will never be performed.

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do this, is by using regex (**and this shall capture all cases**):

```
def parse_str(num: str):
    """
    Parse a string that is expected to contain a number.
    :param num: str. the number in string.
    :return: float or int. Parsed num.
    """
    if not isinstance(num, str):  # check type
        raise TypeError('num should be a str. Got {}.'.format(type(num)))
    clean_num = num.replace(" ", "").upper()  # get rid of spaces & make it uppercase
    if clean_num in ('NAN', '+NAN', '-NAN', '+INF', 'INF', '-INF'):
        return float(clean_num)
    if re.compile('^-?\d+$').search(clean_num):
        return int(clean_num)
    if re.compile('^-?(\d*\.\d+)|(\d+\.\d*)$').search(clean_num):
        return float(clean_num)
    raise ValueError('num is not a number. Got {}.'.format(num))
```

### Notes on Regex Pattern

```
^      beginning of string
$      end of string
-?     match zero or one instance of "-" sign
\d+    one or many digits
\d*    none or many digits
\.     literal dot
|      or
```

### Test  (note the inserted spaces)

```
print(parse_str('1'))
print(parse_str('-999'))
print(parse_str('1   .   2'))
print(parse_str('.3'))
print(parse_str('4.'))
print(parse_str('- 1  2.3  4'))
print(parse_str('    0.5    '))
print(parse_str('nan'))
print(parse_str('-nan'))
print(parse_str('inf'))
print(parse_str('-inf'))
print(parse_str('+nan'))
print(parse_str('+inf'))
print(parse_str('X Y Z'))  # this should throw error
```

### Result

```
1
-999
1.2
0.3
4.0
-12.34
0.5
nan
nan
inf
-inf
nan
inf
ValueError: num is not a number. Got XYZ.
```

Comment: I found a problem when the value is negative, these expressions don't match it because it doesn't match "-". I added `-?` after `\s*`, so that it can match negative sign.

Answer (score 1):

```
lineVal = ['1850', '-0.373', '-0.339', '-0.425']

lineVal2 = [ float(x) if re.search(r'\.',x) else int(x) for x in lineVal ]

LineVal2 output ==> [1850, -0.373, -0.339, -0.425]
```

I'm new bee, I tried it, seem to work for me.

Comment: I don't think this would work for `'1.00'`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Example for a short function:
Returns the numeric type of a string (float or int),
for non-numeric strings the str type is returned.

```
def numeric_type_of_string(string: str):
    if string.isnumeric():
        return int
    try:
        val = float(string)
        return int if val == int(val) else float
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        return str
```

In case you directly want the converted value simply modify the return value:

```
def string_to_numeric_if_possible(string: str):
    if string.isnumeric():
        return int(string)
    try:
        val = float(string)
        return int(val) if val == int(val) else val
    except (TypeError, ValueError):
        return string
```

Comment: Please show the output for some different types.

Comment: Which type are you missing?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an interesting solution using `eval()`. Note: using eval is highly dangerous and not recommended in production environments or anywhere that `eval()` might receive user input! Consider this an academically interesting answer only.

```
def get_string_type(x):
    if type(x) != str:
        raise ValueError('Input must be a string!')
    try:
        string_type = type(eval(x))
    except NameError:
        string_type = str
    return string_type
```

Since Eval treats the string as raw code, this works for any type you can enter into a repl. Example

```
>>> from decimal import Decimal
>>> my_test_string = 'Decimal(0.5)'
>>> type(my_test_string)
<class 'str'>
>>> get_string_type(my_test_string)
<class 'decimal.Decimal'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got to thinking that the request was to convert a number stored as a string to wither an  or , whichever is the tightest data type.  The following function fulfills the request (but does not check if the input is a valid value, i.e. a number an not alpha characters).

The `str_to_float_or_int()` converts a number stored as a string to a `<float>` or an `<int>`.  Although all integers can be floats, an `<int>` is returned wherever possible to meet the "convert to tightest data type" criteria as when:

- input = a whole number.
- input = a characteristic with a 0 mantissa ('1.0')
- input = a characteristic without a mantissa ('1.')

This technique uses the `str.isdecimal()` to determine if the string is a value (vs. a null) and the `<str>.split(".")` method to parse the string value (candidate number) into two parts:

1. integer = number before the decimal
2. Mantissa = number after the decimal place

The built-in `<str>.split(".")` method returns a list.  In this case, list is of the following format:  `[integer, mantissa]`

Note:  Technically, the use of the term 'integer' here really
       refers to the 'characteristic'.  I used 'integer' because 
       it has less characters and thus easier to use in coding.

```
def str_to_float_or_int(value_str, ShowExtended=False):
    # Convert a number stored as a string to a <float> or an <int> 
    # whichever is the "tightest" data type. 

    # Default condition is that the number is a <float>
    isfloat = True
    value = float(value_str)
    numberParsed = value_str.split(".")
    if len(numberParsed) > 1:
        integer = numberParsed[0]
        mantissa = numberParsed[1]
        if integer.isdecimal() and mantissa.isdecimal():
            if int(mantissa) == 0:
                # value is an integer; mantissa is 0
                isfloat = False
                value = int(integer)
            elif integer.isdecimal():
                # value is an integer because a value is only
                # returned for 'integer' variable by .split(), 
                # the returned mantissa value is null.
                isfloat = False
                value = int(integer)
        else:
            # value is an integer because .split() returned
            # a single value list.
            isfloat = False
            value = int(value_str)
        if ShowExtended:
            print("testValue: " + value_str + " | splits into: ", 
                   numberParsed,"\n value: ", value)
            if isfloat:
                print("It's a <float> (;o)\n")
            else:
                print("It's an <int> {:o)~\n")
        return value
```

---

Run Script from the Console to test str_to_float_or_int()

---

```
testValues = ["0.80", "1.00", "5", ".1", "4."]
print("\n-----------------------------------------------\n" +
        "| Testcase:  ", testValues, " |\n" +
        "-----------------------------------------------")
for number in testValues:
    str_to_float_or_int(number, ShowExtended=True)
```

> ---
>
> Output Results (copied from the console)
>
> ---

```
>   ---------------------------------------------------
>   |  Testcase:   ['0.80', '1.00', '5', '.1', '4.']  |
>   ---------------------------------------------------
>   testValue: 0.80 | splits into:  ['0', '80']
>   value:  0.8
>   It's a <float> (;o)
>   
>   testValue: 1.00 | splits into:  ['1', '00']
>   value:  1
>   It's an <int> {:o)~
>   
>   testValue: 5 | splits into:  ['5']
>   value:  5
>   It's an <int> {:o)~
>   
>   testValue: .1 | splits into:  ['', '1']
>   value:  0.1
>   It's a <float> (;o)
>
>   testValue: 4. | splits into:  ['4', '']
>   value:  4
>   It's an <int> {:o)~
```

Answer (score 0):

this simple function can tackle the problem, you just need the "Solution" block of code.

intOrfloat.py:

```
import sys
def NumberType(argv):
    Number = argv[1]
    try:
        float(Number)   # Exception if not a number
        ################ Solution ################
        if '.' not in Number:
            return '%s is Integer'%(Number)
        if int(Number.split('.')[1]) > 0:
            return '%s is Float'%(Number)
        else:
            return '%s is Integer'%(Number)
        ##########################################
    except Exception as e:
        return '%s is Text...'%(Number)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(NumberType(sys.argv))
```

tests:

```
>python intOrfloat.py 0.80
0.80 is Float

>python intOrfloat.py 1.00
1.00 is Integer

>python intOrfloat.py 9999999999999999
9999999999999999 is Integer
```

So, no need to worry about the size of integer number.

```
'.' not in Number              # number without decimal must be an integer
Number.split('.')              # split into [integer String, decimal String]
Number.split('.')[1]           # get decimal String
int(Number.split('.')[1])      # convert it into decimal Number
int(Number.split('.')[1]) > 0  # decimal Number > 0 = Float; Otherwise, Integer
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer instead of posting just code.