# How can I verify that a variable is a number in Python?

Tags: python

I am writing a code on the subject of engineering which requires the user to input several values which the program will then work with.

At the moment I have the following code:

```
while True:
    strainx =input("Please enter a value for strain in the x-direction: ")

    num_format = re.compile("^[1-9][0-9]*\.?[0-9]*")
    isnumber = re.match(num_format,strainx)
    if isnumber:

        break
```

In simple terms I am trying to ask the user to enter a value for strainx which is a number. If the user enters anything other than a number then the question will be repeated until they enter a number. However, by using this method the code does not accept decimals and there will be instances where the user must enter a decimal. Is there any way around this?

Comment: this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357422/python-determine-if-a-string-should-be-converted-into-int-or-float

Comment: Could this question be rephrased as "How can I verify that a variable is a number?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Checking if a string can be converted to float in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/736043/checking-if-a-string-can-be-converted-to-float-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

Just try casting to a float and catching a ValueError if the user enters something that cannot be cast:

```
while True:
    strainx = input("Please enter a value for strain in the x-direction: ")  
    try:
       number = float(strainx)
       break # if valid entry we break the loop
    except ValueError:
        # or else we get here, print message and ask again
        print("Invalid entry")

print(number)
```

casting to float covers both `"1"` a `"1.123"` etc..

If you don't want to accept zero you can check after casting is the number is zero, I presume negative numbers are also invalid so we can check if the number is not <= 0.

```
while True:
    strainx = input("Please enter a value for strain in the x-direction: ")
    try:
        number = float(strainx)
        if number <= 0:
            print("Number must be greater than zero")
            continue  # input was either negative or 0
        break  # if valid entry we break the loop
    except ValueError:
        # or else we get here, print message and ask again
        print("Invalid entry")

print(number)
```

Comment: This is [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-eafp); it’s easier to ask for forgiveness than permission. Just assume that it’s a vaid number and catch the case where it is not.

Comment: Okay great thanks, that works! I have several of these inputs. For one of them I want to specify that the input cannot equal zero either, is there any way of doing this?

Comment: Sure. After trying to cast add an if check to see if number is zero. If so print a message then use continue putting the break outside the if

Comment: I've been trying to write this into the program and I really don't understand how. Could you possibly give me some more guidance? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for Integer check then try this -

```
isinstance( variable_name, int )
```

If it returns True then the variable is number else it's something else.

But if you want to check if the character value is number or not. eg - a = "2"
above script will return False.
So try this -

```
try:
    number = float(variable_name)
    print "variable is number"
except ValueError:
    print "Not a number"
```

Comment: Assuming Python 3, the return value of `input` will always be a string regardless of its content, so the `instanceof` check will never work there.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 2, instead of using regular expressions, you can use Python's in built type checking mechanisms.

Let's loop while strainx is not a number, then check whether the latest input is a number.

```
is_number = False
while not is_number:
    strainx =input("Please enter a value for strain in the x-direction: ")
    is_number = isinstance(strainx, float) or isinstance(strainx, int)
```

Comment: how would a string ever be an instance of a float or int?

Comment: `input()` in Python 2.X will cast the input to a sensible data type, i.e 'x' would be string, 2 would be int, 2.2 would be float.

Comment: How would the user be using a regex on something that is not a string?

Comment: Input returns a string in python 3

Comment: There's no reason to assume that the programmer has not made an error by expecting to use regex. I previously asked for further clarification in the comments section to see if they were asking the question he intended to.

Comment: I disagree, but feel free to explain your reasoning.

Comment: @MattDavidson You do realize that `input` returns a string.

Comment: I do, but its behaviour has changed to that in Python 3. My answer is correct for Python 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you insist of using regex, this pattern appears to work:

```
"^(\-)?[\d]*(\.[\d]*)?$"
```

Match optional negative sign, match any number of digits, optional decimal with any number of digits.

Tip: You can use `isnumber = bool(re.match(num_format,strainx)` or the latter part directly into the if statement.

Comment: You don’t need to put single character class escape sequences (`\d`) into separate character classes (`[ ]`). And you also don’t need to escape dashes. You could shorten your expression to just `^-?\d*(\.\d*)?$`. And if you use `re.match`, you don’t actually need the caret `^`.