# Function not working as intended, python, TKinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, variables, tkinter

Im having trouble calling an variable from a function within another function.

I have two functions:

```
def refineRate(event):

    if refineRate(event) == int():
        refine = int(refineRate(event))
        return refine

    else:
        refine = float(refineRate(event))
        return refine
```

and:

```
def veldCalc(event):

    minValue = open("mineral_value.csv", "r")
    veld = minValue.readlines()[0]
    minValue.close()
    veld = veld[0:3]
    veld = int(veld)
    veld = veld / 100 * refineRate(event)
    refinedVeld = veld * int(veldCalc)
    print (refinedVeld)
```

I also have two entry where the user of the calculator can enter some figures.

```
repro = Label(root, text="Reprocessing %")
repro_entry = Entry(root)
repro.grid(row=0, column=0)
repro_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)


veld = Label(root, text="Veldspar: ")
veld_entry = Entry(root)
veld.grid(row=1, column=0)
veld_entry.grid(row=1, column=1)

repro_entry.bind("<KeyPress>", refineRate)
veld_entry.bind("<KeyPress>", veldCalc)
```

What i need is for the user to input there `refineRate` and which should then get passed through the function and stored for later use. the when they enter the amount they have, the `veldCalc` function should then pull the users refine rate from the previous function and do the math but im getting the following errors

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ganjena\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1699, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Ganjena/Desktop/Course/Projects/helloworld/ORE FUNCTIONS/Ore Calculator.py", line 5, in refineRate
    if refineRate(event) == int():
  File "C:/Users/Ganjena/Desktop/Course/Projects/helloworld/ORE FUNCTIONS/Ore Calculator.py", line 5, in refineRate
    if refineRate(event) == int():
  File "C:/Users/Ganjena/Desktop/Course/Projects/helloworld/ORE FUNCTIONS/Ore Calculator.py", line 5, in refineRate
    if refineRate(event) == int():
  [Previous line repeated 990 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceede
```

any idea to why this isn't working? Thank you in advance.

Comment: The recursion in your first function will never stop, you always have a recursive call in your `if` condition...

Comment: ok i think i understand, and how could i stop this? but its not a loop so why does it continue to run itself?

Comment: Because it's a recursive function that always calls itself, like try `def f(): f()` You never reach your else block because each time you call the function, it checks the `if` condition, and calls itself again... endlessly (well, until Python errors you out). And indeed, you **always** end up using a recursive call... so I don't know what you expect to happen or what your function is usppose to do.

Comment: all i want it to do is take the user input check if its a `int` or a `float` and then store it to be used in the `veldCalc` funtion

Comment: The rest of your code is very strange as well. For example, in your second function, what do you expect `veld * int(veldCalc)` to do? `veldCalc` is the function itself!

Comment: If you want t check if a variable refers to an `int` or `float` the use the built-in `isinstance()`

Comment: hmm i haven't got round to learning about `isinstance` ill look into it. the `veld * int(veldCalc)` should be the `veld` taken from the file * the users input which is bound to that function

Comment: basically, what i want there is the user to input how much veld they have and then that `veldCalc` function first takes the base rate of veld, subtracts the `refineRate` value and then multiply it by the users input (which is binded to the `veldCalc` function)

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a misconception of how to get the user-input value inside a `tk.Entry` widget. The proper way is to use the `.get()` method on the widget.

Here is a minimal example to get you started:

```
# (Use Tkinter/tkinter depending on Python version)
import Tkinter as tk 

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.repro = tk.Label(self, text="Reprocessing %")
        self.repro_entry = tk.Entry(self)
        self.repro.grid(row=0, column=0)
        self.repro_entry.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.repro_entry.bind("<Return>", self.refineRate)
        self.mainloop()

    def refineRate(self, evt):
        # Get the user input and print it in the terminal
        userRepro = self.repro_entry.get()
        print(userRepro)

# Launch the GUI
app = App()
```

Then, to check whether the user input is a float or an int, you can use the technique described in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15357477/4084269).