# How to change a list of str items to either float, int, bool, or str depending on what they are?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If I have a list of lists that consists of `str` data initially, how could I alter that list to what the `str` represent? For example:

```
x = [['3.14', 'Pi and radius', '20', 'False', False', '10'],
     ['201', 'Eulers', 'True', '9.18922', 'False', '12', '90']]
```

to

```
x = [[3.14, 'Pi and radius', 20, False, False, 10],
     [201, 'Eulers', True, 9.18922, False, 12, 90]]
```

Where the `str` have been altered to `float`, `int`, `bool`, or kept as `str`, depending on what they actually are.

I think a `for i in range(len(x))` loop is required, and `if type(x) = ...`, but I'm not sure on the specifics.

Comment: So you may acknowledge every good answer by upvoting it, and the best one by accepting it (click at the check mark), too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ast.literal_eval()`. The code below demonstrates the usage.

```
import ast

values = ["hello", "1", "1.5", "False"]

def real_type(value):
    try:
        return ast.literal_eval(value)
    except:
        return value

x=[real_type(i) for i in values]
print(x)
print(x[1] + x[2])
```

Prints

> `["hello", 1, 1.5, False]`
>   `2.5`

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

> define your own `isdigit()` function which works for `float` and `int`
>   both because default `isdigit()` only works for `int` :

```
x = [['3.14', 'Pi and radius', '20', 'False', 'False', '10'],
     ['201', 'Eulers', 'True', '9.18922', 'False', '12', '90']]


def isdigit(digit):   #define your own isdigit() function which works for float and int both because default isdigit() only works for int
    try:
        float(digit)
        return 0
    except ValueError:
        return 1


check={'True':True,'False':False}  #define True , False dict
```

Now :

> In one line solution:

```
list_1=[[float(sub_item) if '.' in sub_item else int(sub_item) if isdigit(sub_item) == 0 else check.get(sub_item) if sub_item == 'True' or sub_item == 'False' else sub_item for sub_item in item]for item in x]
print(list_1)
```

output:

```
[[3.14, 'Pi and radius', 20, False, False, 10], [201, 'Eulers', True, 9.18922, False, 12, 90]]
```

> Detailed Solution:

Above list comprehension is same as :

```
final_list=[]   # logic is from here
for item in x:
    if isinstance(item,list):
        sub_list=[]   
        #sub_list for keep tracking of nested list in origional list
        for sub_item in item:
            if isdigit(sub_item)==0:  #passing value to isdigit() function
                if '.' in sub_item:    #float contain '.' 
                    sub_list.append(float(sub_item))
                else:                  #else it will be int
                    sub_list.append(int(sub_item))
            elif sub_item=='True' or sub_item=='False': 
                sub_list.append(check.get(sub_item))  #get value from check dict
            else:
                sub_list.append(sub_item)  #else append remaining items

        final_list.append(sub_list)

print(final_list)
```

output:

```
[[3.14, 'Pi and radius', 20, False, False, 10], [201, 'Eulers', True, 9.18922, False, 12, 90]]
```

Answer (score -1):

You could define a function like convert() and in convert check the type and apply the conversion.

```
converted_list = [convert(i) for i in x]
```

or

```
converted_list = map(convert(),x)
```

convert could be something like this (requires literal_value to be imported from ast): https://stackoverflow.com/a/41475449/4040842 @ Shrewmouse

Shrewmouse's solution does not require if else statements.

Answer (score -1):

You are right, but instead of `len()` function you may use more Pythonic way with `enumerate()`:

```
x = [['3.14', 'Pi and radius', '20', 'False', 'False', '10'],
     ['201', 'Eulers', 'True', '9.18922', 'False', '12', '90']]

for lst in x:
    for i, val in enumerate(lst):
        try:
            val = float(val)
            if val == int(val):
                val = int(val)
        except ValueError:
            if val == "True":
               val = True
            elif val == "False":
                val = False
        lst[i] = val


print(x)
```

Output:

> [[3.14, 'Pi and radius', 20, False, False, 10], [201, 'Eulers', True, 9.18922, False, 12, 90]]

Comment: Although it does the job ,this shouldn't be marked the solution. It only does the job for this particular situation. If a new type is added, the code would have to be modified. So, **0** for scalability and generality. Not nice either. No reason to downvote, but reason for upvoting other answers (Jebby's).

Comment: Like @ChrisFati said. This is not scalable. If your dataset contains say a dictionary, this will not handle it. My answer is scalable to any (built in at least) type.