# How to print the input as an integer, float or string in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, input

The purpose of my code is for the output to give the number and the type of the input. For instance:

If the input is: `10`

The output should be: `10 is an integer`

If the input is: `10.0`

The output should be: `10.0 is a float`

If the input is: `Ten`

The output should be: `Ten is a string`

I am quite a beginner with programming so I don't know any "advanced" functions yet. I shouldn't have to use it either because this is a starting school assignment. Normally I should be able to solve this with if, elif and else statements and maybe some `int ()`, `float ()` and `type ()` functions.

```
x = input("Enter a number: ")

if type(int(x)) == int:
    print( x, " is an integer")
elif type(float(x)) == float:
    print( x, "is a float")
else:
    print(x, "is a string")
```

However, I keep getting stuck because the input is always given as a string. So I think I should convert this to an integer / float only if I put this in an if, elif, else statements, then logically an error will come up. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: Checkout [Python, Determine if a string should be converted into Int or Float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357422/python-determine-if-a-string-should-be-converted-into-int-or-float)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python, Determine if a string should be converted into Int or Float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15357422/python-determine-if-a-string-should-be-converted-into-int-or-float)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**REMEMBER**: [`Easy to ask forgiveness than to ask for permission (EAFP)`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265451/ask-forgiveness-not-permission-explain)

You can use `try`/`except`:

```py
x = input("Enter a number: ")
try:
    _ = float(x)
    try:
        _ = int(x)
        print(f'{x} is integer')
    except ValueError:
        print(f'{x} is float')
except ValueError:
    print(f'{x} is string')
```

**SAMPLE RUN**:

```py
x = input("Enter a number: ")
Enter a number: >? 10
10 is ineger

x = input("Enter a number: ")
Enter a number: >? 10.0
10.0 is float

x = input("Enter a number: ")
Enter a number: >? Ten
Ten is string
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it'll always be a string, what you can do is check the format of the string:

Case 1: All characters are numeric (it's int)

Case 2: All numeric characters but have exactly one '.' in between (it's a float)

Everything else: it's a string

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
def get_type(x):
    ' Detects type '
    if x.isnumeric():
        return int      # only digits
    elif x.replace('.', '', 1).isnumeric():
        return float    # single decimal
    else:
        return None

# Using get_type in OP code
x = input("Enter a number: ")

x_type = get_type(x)
if x_type == int:
    print( x, " is an integer")
elif x_type == float:
    print( x, "is a float")
else:
    print(x, "is a string")
```

**Example Runs**

```
Enter a number: 10
10  is an integer

Enter a number: 10.
10. is a float

Enter a number: 10.5.3
10.5.3 is a string
```