# How to make Python to check is variable a number or letter?

Tags: python

Hi I have a question...

As a Python beginner I want to ask how do I make my code to check is **input** from a user **a number** or **a letter** ?

```
if age == int or float:
    print("Ok, zavrsili smo sa osnovnim informacijama! Da li zelite da ih uklopimo i pokazemo Vase osnovne informacije? DA ili NE ?")

elif age == False:
    print("Hej, to nije broj... Pokusaj ponovo")
```

This is part of my code that I'm having issues with. I want to make statement **if user inputs his age as number, the code continues**. But, **if user inputs something that is not a number, code tells him to start all over**( all print statements are written in Serbian, I hope you don't mind :D)

Comment: You can use function [isnumeric](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_isnumeric.asp) to check if input is a integer. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67432467/how-to-print-the-input-as-an-integer-float-or-string-in-python/67432634#67432634) shows how this can be used to create a function to check if a string is int, float or non-numeric string.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking if a string can be converted to float in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/736043/checking-if-a-string-can-be-converted-to-float-in-python)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This site is meant for specific questions you've already [tried to find the answer yourself](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). It's a good idea to [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=python+string+is+number) your question first to see if answers are easy to find.

Comment: What is the range of acceptable numeric values, i.e. positive real numbers, all real numbers, any sequence consisting of only digits?

Comment: I'm not sure did I expressed myself correctly. I need my code to print an error message when user types something that isn't a number like eg. letters...

Comment: @AkaMadafaka--did you check out get_type in my link above?  It shows how to check if input is an int or float.  If it's still not clear I can post some code.

Comment: You can use 'type' or 'isinstance' functions [Check This Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/402704/8289026)

Comment: @DarrylG If you can post code sure, I would love to check it out.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to determine a Python variable's type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/402504/how-to-determine-a-python-variables-type)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you are getting the value 'age' from the user via an input(..) call then to check if the `age` is a number then:

```
age = input('Provide age >')
if age.isnumeric():
    age = int(age)
    print("Ok, zavrsili smo sa osnovnim informacijama! Da li zelite da ih uklopimo i pokazemo Vase osnovne informacije? DA ili NE ?")
else:
     print("Hej, to nije broj... Pokusaj ponovo")
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to prompt the user for input in a `while` loop, `try` to convert it to a `float`, and `break` if you're successful.

```
while True:
    try:
        age = float(input("Please enter your age as a number: "))
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("That's not a number, please try again!")

# age is guaranteed to be a numeric value (float) -- proceed!
```

Comment: This, IMHO, is the cleanest solution and goes about it via a `try`/`except`

Answer (score 0):

```
isinstance(x, int) # True
```

Or you can try

Use assert statement

```
assert <condition>,<error message>
```

for example

```
assert type(x) == int, "error"
```

Comment: since this should be a logic check, then I think most developers would say that `assert` is the wrong thing here.

Comment: Not sure cause the custom message is specified here

Comment: Nothing to do with having a message - asserts are meant for debugging and maybe unit testing - asserts are very easy to disable, which is why they shouldn't be used for what is actually end user reporting or program logic.

Comment: He could use isinstance(x, int) than , the requirement is clear thought

Comment: it depends how the code is collecting the variable - if the variable is coming from input(...) it will be a string - so prossibly better to use `.isnumeric()` method (since that isinstance check will fail on a string, and the only way to make it work would be to pass the string to `int()` - and then you have to worry about exceptions. `isnumeric()` avoids that.

Comment: While this work, it seems that the OP is about result from `input()`. Which is always a string, so I think `isnumeric` or `isdigit` may be the better way to check whether the input is convertable to a number.

Answer (score 0):

Using function to check type of string

```
def get_type(s):
    ''' Detects type of string s
    
       Return int if int, float if float, or None for non-numeric string '''
    if s.isnumeric():
        return int      # only digits
    elif s.replace('.', '', 1).isnumeric():
        return float    # single decimal
    else:
        return None     # returns None for non-numeric string


# Using function
age = input("What is your age?")
if not get_type(age) is None:
    print(f'Valid age {age}')
else:
    print(f'Value {age} is not a valid age')
```

Example runs

```
What is your age?25
Valid age 25

What is your age?12.5
Valid age 12.5

What is your age?12.3.5
Value 12.3.5 is not a valid age
```